# How to generate document for boost date_time

Tags: boost, document, generate, boost-date-time

I select boost 1.80.0

Boost page link is not work , I got three doc link form [boost. date_time_document page](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/date_time.html)

1. http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/libraries/date_time/date_time.pdf
2. http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/libraries/date_time/ref_guide/index.html
3. http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/libraries/date_time/index.html

but they are can't access.

[On project](https://github.com/boostorg/date_time/blob/develop/xmldoc/date_time_docs_howto.html)  , I found `bjam --v2 date_time_doc`

1. on date_time project execuate the command failed
2. on boost project another command `./b2 --v2 date_time_doc` not got document

I want to get `boost.date_time` subproject document, class method note...

Will anyone try to help me?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions you found in the project are old. That hasn't worked [since 2006](https://github.com/boostorg/date_time/commit/0f7188c4c2eefa823e84ac3b1e72d4bb64e90e4b).

Instead, I found you can

```
cd xmldoc
b2
```

And the docs will be generated in xmldoc/html:

```
google-chrome html/index.html
```

[image]

Note that I did this locally from the 1.80.0 release tar ball. However, be aware that there can be quite a slew of requirements to build the documentation. I usually start off with Debian's

```
apt build-dep libboost-all-dev
```

But I do remember having to manually install extra stuff for quickbook/docbook.

Comment: Thank you share your experience , maby the page you got is same with official : https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/date_time.html

Comment: I don't think it's detailed enough , `doxygen` maby helpful .

Comment: Is there a question? I think I may not understand your comments.